How to get typescript compilation error on signal variable from ngrx selectSignal function?
I am using ngrx selectSignal() to select a state slice of my ngrx store. It returns a Signal of my object instead of an Observable. So far so good.
But there is no typescript errors, if I try to assign a value to this signal object. I only get an error in runtime, which is often too late, if I don't catch the error myself in local development runtime.
example:
// defining and setting the signal variable
    public voucherFilterSignal: Signal<VoucherFilter> =
        this._store.selectSignal(selectVoucherFilter);

...


// assigning a new value to the signal (i expect my editor to give me a typescript error here, but all is fine - but it will break in runtime)
    this.voucherFilterSignal().search = 'someNewValue';

I seem to have kinda workaround to add Readonly type when declaring the variable, so typescript compiler catches it in the editor. I'm still confused why this is not the default, as the runtime catches it.
    public voucherFilterSignal: Signal<Readonly<VoucherFilter>> =
        this._store.selectSignal(selectVoucherFilter);

...

    this.voucherFilterSignal().search = 'someNewValue'; // now correctly gives typescript error "Cannot assign to 'search' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)"


What type is returned from this._store.selectSignal(selectVoucherFilter)?

Signal<VoucherFilter> is returned, which is correct. I'm confused about why it in runtime catches it correctly with the error error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'search' because it is a read-only property. but in typescript compiler it can't catch it.

I see, it would be helpful if you could provide a minimal reproducible example that shows the problem or error you're encountering, ideally in an online code editor like Stackblitz.

@Verity Because of setting up a new ngrx store in a online code editor from scratch is a little tough, i hope you can do with this simple instrucitons: 1) declare and set a variable using selectSignal() that selects and object from your ngrx store. 2) assign a new value to a property in that object. You will see no error in the editor, but if you run the code in runtime, you will get the error.

Unless Angular adds immutability to nested objects of the Signal type, then there is only 2 solutions: 1) add a custom immutable type, that i need to use everytime 2) add a custom ESLint rule. I will go with the custom ESLint rule.
